# Angular-cli beta 14 not building my Angular2 app which worked fine with systemjs

Tags: angular, typescript

I use VSCode on Windows 10 and I have an app at angular 2 final that works perfectly with systemjs.  I have installed the angular-cli beta 14 webpack version and followed the steps in the upgrade document [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.14).

I am getting a multitude of errors that it can't find Map, Require, Promise...etc: Here is a sample:

ERROR in [default] E:\development\ketogeniqweb\node_modules\@angular\compiler\src\compile_metadata.d.ts:348:14
Cannot find name 'Set'.

```
ERROR in [default] E:\development\ketogeniqweb\node_modules\@angular\compiler\src\directive_normalizer.d.ts:19:99
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] E:\development\ketogeniqweb\node_modules\@angular\compiler\src\directive_normalizer.d.ts:21:73
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] E:\development\ketogeniqweb\node_modules\@angular\compiler\src\offline_compiler.d.ts:15:25
Cannot find name 'Map'.
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "migration-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "guid": "0.0.12",
    "moment": "^2.15.0",
    "primeng": "^1.0.0-beta.15",
    "primeui": "^4.1.15",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.32",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.33",
    "@types/jquery": "^1.10.31",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.1.26",
    "@types/webpack": "^1.12.34",
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.14",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.5",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "mapRoot": "/",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../dist/",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "inlineSources": true
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "typings.d.ts"
  ],
  "types": [
    "jasmine",
    "jquery",
    "lodash",
    "node",
    "source-map",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
  ]
}
```

My project will not build under beta14 cli and I can't figure it out. I've found numerous reports of this in other programs, but the fixes apparently don't apply here as I tried a bunch of them.  Can someone please point me to what I need to do to make this build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are using windows or visual studio, but people seem to be having difficult with that sorta setup... https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2058

Comment: OKay.. I filed a report there also.  I may have to go back to beta 10 so I can continue to work on it.

Comment: @JohnBaird - what IDE are you using?  I was having big issues with similar errors in Webstorm..  I did a couple things like remove the typescript compiling within Webstorm (since it was using version 1.8 and not 2.0) and allowed the ng serve to do it.. I setup a run profile within Webstorm.

I also removed this line from the tsconfig.json:  `"lib": ["es6: dom"]`

Comment: using VSCode, I'll try removing the line from the tsconfig.json.